# React Navigation 5 - stack, tab and drawer navigation in all screens like Twitter

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native and I'm having a problem with react navigation, basically I want to use the bottom tab and drawer menu together in all screens but following some examples and tutorials I dont get what I want. I want that the drawer menu and the bottom tab appear in all screens like Twitter, every screens of the sidebar have the bottom tab and the active icon in the tab is always the home icon. I tried putting the bottom tab component inside the drawer but the other screens like profile, calendar, account settings(...), dont have the bottom tab.

My code:

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const FeedStack = createStackNavigator();
const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const FeedStackScreen = () => (
  <FeedStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <FeedStack.Screen name='Feed' component={FeedScreen} />
    <FeedStack.Screen name='AddEvent' component={AddEventScreen} />
    <FeedStack.Screen name='Event' component={EventScreen} />
  </FeedStack.Navigator>
);

const TabsScreen = () => (
  <Tabs.Navigator
    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    tabBarOptions={{ showLabel: false }}
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => {
        let iconName;

        if (route.name === 'Feed') {
          iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home';
          color = focused ? '#1ba8cf' : '#666666';
        } else if (route.name === 'Notifications') {
          iconName = focused ? 'bell' : 'bell';
          color = focused ? '#1ba8cf' : '#666666';
        }
        return (
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={iconName}
            size={20}
            color={color}
            style={{ textAlignVertical: 'center' }}
          />
        );
      }
    })}
  >
    <Tabs.Screen name='Feed' component={FeedStackScreen} />
    <Tabs.Screen name='Notifications' component={NotificationsScreen} />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
);

const EventsCalendarStackScreen = () => (
  <EventsCalendarStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <EventsCalendarStack.Screen
      name='EventsCalendar'
      component={EventsCalendarScreen}
    />
  </EventsCalendarStack.Navigator>
);

const DrawerNavigatior = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator
    drawerPosition='right'
    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    initialRouteName='Feed'
    drawerContent={(props) => Sidebar(props)}
  >
    <Drawer.Screen
      name='EventsCalendar'
      component={EventsCalendarStackScreen}
      options={{ title: 'Calendário' }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name='Configurations'
      component={ConfigurationsScreen}
      options={{ title: 'Configurações' }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name='About'
      component={AboutScreen}
      options={{ title: 'Descobre quem somos' }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name='Team'
      component={TeamScreen}
      options={{ title: 'Conhece a Equipa' }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name='Contact'
      component={ContactScreen}
      options={{ title: 'Contacto' }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name='Terms'
      component={TermsScreen}
      options={{ title: 'Termos' }}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      name='Policy'
      component={PolicyScreen}
      options={{ title: 'Política de Privacidade' }}
    />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
);

return (
  <MenuProvider>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <AppStack.Screen name='Drawer' component={DrawerNavigatior} />
      </AppStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </MenuProvider>
);
```

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Making the tabs a screen of your drawer is a good idea. If you want to see the tabs on the calendar screen for example you could put them in a stack navigator that is a screen of your tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/), you can nest your navigators.

To use `navigation.openDrawer()`, `navigation.closeDrawer()` or `navigation.toggleDrawer()` in deeper navigators you can use `dispatch` from `navigation` object and use `DrawerActions` to emit commands to nearest drawer navigator.

So you can do things like above:

```js
//HomeStackScreen.js

import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeScreen = () => (
  <View>
    <Text> Your Home View </Text>
  </View>
);

export default function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

HomeStackScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  //other options
  headerLeft: () => <YourButtonComponent onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())} />
});
```

```js
//SearchStackScreen.js

import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const SearchScreen = () => (
  <View>
    <Text> Your Search View </Text>
  </View>
);

export default function SearchStackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
    <Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

SearchStackScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  //other options
  headerLeft: () => <YourButtonComponent onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())} />
});
```

```js
//NotificationStackScreen.js

import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const NotificationScreen = () => (
  <View>
    <Text> Your Notification View </Text>
  </View>
);

export default function NotificationStackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="NotificationScreen" component={NotificationScreen} />
    <Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

NotificationStackScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  //other options
  headerLeft: () => <YourButtonComponent onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())} />
});
```

```js
//DirectMessagesStackScreen.js

import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const DirectMessagesScreen = () => (
  <View>
    <Text> Your Direct Messages View </Text>
  </View>
);

export default function DirectMessagesStackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="DirectMessagesScreen" component={DirectMessagesScreen} />
    <Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

DirectMessagesStackScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  //other options
  headerLeft: () => <YourButtonComponent onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())} />
});
```

```js
//BottomTabNavigator.js

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tab'
import HomeStackScreen from './HomeStackScreen'
import SearchStackScreen from './SearchStackScreen'
import NotificationStackScreen from './NotificationStackScreen'
import DirectMessagesStackScreen from './DirectMessagesStackScreen'

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="HomeStackScreen" component={HomeStackScreen} options={HomeStackScreen.navigationOptions}/>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="SearchStackScreen" component={SearchStackScreen} options={SearchStackScreen.navigationOptions}/>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="NotificationStackScreen" component={NotificationStackScreen} options={NotificationStackScreen.navigationOptions}/>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="DirectMessagesStackScreen" component={DirectMessagesStackScreen} options={DirectMessagesStackScreen.navigationOptions}/>
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

```js
//RootStack.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import BottomTabNavigator from './BottomTabNavigator'

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function Root() {
  return (
    <NavigatorContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="RootScreen" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigatorContainer>
  )

}
```